# Gcloud pub/sub ignoring configuration?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I have project A and project B in my google cloud. I have my configuration set to project A, but when I try and use my pub/sub reliant python scripts, the look for the subscription in project B, which then gives this error:

```
google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound: 404 projects/PROJECT_B/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_NAME
```

I should note that I do not encounter this error on my machine, but it happens on a linux test server.

Also, running the commands

```
gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions list
gcloud beta pubsub topics list
```

List the subscriptions and topics in project A.

Answer (score 0):

Project used in request is derived from `--project` flag, if that is not set then it is pulled from `core/project` project property.

You can see current property settings via

```
gcloud config list
```

The property can be set via

```
gcloud config set core/project PROJECT_A
```

This has to be done on every machine you use `gcloud` on as these settings are **local** to the machine. They are usually stored in `~/.config/gcloud` directory. You can use `gcloud info` command to see which directory credentials and other settings/properties are stored in.